# Exact generalised harmonic numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

The [generalised harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) of order \$m\$ of \$n\$ is

$$H_{n,m} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {k^m}$$

For example, the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) are \$H_{n,1}\$, and \$H_{\infty,2} = \frac {\pi^2} 6\$. These are related to the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) as

$$\zeta(m) = \lim_{n \to \infty} H_{n,m}$$

Given two positive integers \$n > 0\$, \$m > 0\$, output the *exact* rational number \$H_{n,m}\$. The fraction should be reduced to its simplest term (i.e. if it is \$\frac a b\$, \$\gcd(a, b) = 1\$). You may output as a numerator/denominator pair, a rational number or any clear value that distinguishes itself as a rational number. You **may not** output as a floating point number.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
n, m -> Hₙ,ₘ
3, 7 -> 282251/279936
6, 4 -> 14011361/12960000
5, 5 -> 806108207/777600000
4, 8 -> 431733409/429981696
3, 1 -> 11/6
8, 3 -> 78708473/65856000
7, 2 -> 266681/176400
6, 7 -> 940908897061/933120000000
2, 8 -> 257/256
5, 7 -> 2822716691183/2799360000000
```

Comment: Brownie points for beating/matching my 4 byte M answer

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224401/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123173/66833)

Answer (score 9):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 4 bytes

```
Rİ*S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/3/P@jIBq3g////G/83BwA)

Obligatory trivial answer ;-;

```
Rİ*S  Main Link; takes n on the left and m on the right
R     Range: [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
 İ    Inverse/Reciprocal: [1, 1/2, 1/3, ..., 1/n]
  *   Exponent: [1, 1/2^m, 1/3^m, ..., 1/n^m]
   S  Sum
```

Comment: What kind of language is M?  The README just has an.... M.

Comment: @Jonah it's Jelly but using Python's `sympy` for infinite precision math. Or rather, an extremely outdated revision of Jelly lol

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
HarmonicNumber
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yOxKDc/LzPZrzQ3KbXof0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtbGOgnmtDle1mY6CCYg21VEwBdEmOgoWIBoobwiiLXQUjEG0uY6CEVQ9WJ8RVJ0piM9V@x8A)

Naturally.

---

Alternatively, **16 bytes** without the built-in:

```
Tr[Range@#^-#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6QoOigxLz3VQTlOV9koVu1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoODcqxaXXByYl5dNVe1sY6Cea0OV7WZjoIJiDbVUTAF0SY6ChYgGihvCKItdBSMQbS5joIRVD1YnxFUnSmIz1X7HwA)

Comment: I get the feeling there have been Wolfram answers where the built-in is longer than the non-built-in answer.

Comment: @chunes One example given in the Mathematica golfing tips thread is `EuclideanDistance`: it's always shorter to write `(Norm[#-#2]&)`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 29 bytes

```
{sum((1/1..$^n)X**-$^m).nude}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck9CoAgAAbQq3yIREYZ0u9gnaMpCdIpK4qGsM5uOb3h7fpYam9vRAadd@dl41jkgnM6rmxIkoyOlvH1mvXrz@kGoQpdD2fwUPUSmO2AbFD0KWSJOlChCrQoA@I//wE)

This function takes two arguments, `$^m` and `$^n`.  `1/1 .. $^n` is a sequence of rational numbers from `1` to the second argument.  `X** -$^m` produces the exponentiated cross product of that list with the negative of the first argument.  `sum` sums those rational numbers, and `.nude` produces a two-element list of the numerator and denominator of the sum.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 68 bytes

A 1-byte shorter, slightly less readable version with a single recursive call. This is otherwise identical to the commented version below.

```javascript
m=>g=(n,N=0,D=1)=>D?g(n-!!n,n?p=N*n**m+D:D,n?q=D*n**m:N%D):[p/N,q/N]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9LbuJAEN37FJVIkbuhcf/s/hA1bDyz9CZLQiQEhjiCNtgkUhTNDUaazSxn7jHnyQXmCKTtWKlFSa/q1XuvnlYvq3bdVMfzxNeb8rJ1l4Ob7RzypHCM5I5jN8vnO@QnV1ee@PnRFSM/Gh3G@TQP8OTyHk6LmxxPF0dakBMtlpemPD1XTYnibRvjpClXm@/Vvrx79WvEcHKu785N5XcIJ@1xX53R9b2/xsm2br6t1o@oBTeDtwhg4QkcCDRluwQH7UCmiwd6v1mOKb4NnHXt23pfJvs6hOzpi4JA3h1s0QEjjwkUMIaYxqHn4FynB3OI///79f7nd@gxTCF@//szDoI/8EUS0DCZgTBCZJwKba1UkSKQdlOeMs6l4pQLq1ioKCOQdRvDFGdGME211v2KRSkB0@1SybWUKbM0FdYarqyKgg/vFTlVkSEgO6CNZibVkqrMZJ1IpAmIPo5SygRbrdIwVUNIGzSZMVYHc2ql5IJ9ViQGa5FpKjLVxfx6S3OlLOdGDt8NNx8)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 69 bytes

Expects `(m)(n)`. Returns `[numerator, denominator]`.

```javascript
m=>g=(n,N=0,D=1)=>n?g(n-1,p=N*n**m+D,q=D*n**m):D?g(0,D,N%D):[p/N,q/N]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LrtMwEN3nK0ZXQrFbN/bYiR9F7t0EltncZW@RqjYtQa3TJgUJIf4AiQ1L@A@@5/4An1CcEDGLkT3nzDlnPmw/bftd11xui9Du6/vB389@dfQksMoLVnqkfhUejyQskF18NQuz2XlesqsvxyddlhGMRFa9KulyfeEVu/Jqc@/q68emq0l66FOadfV2/7Y51U@fw44Imt3ap1vXhCOhWX85NTfy8BweaHZouzfb3XvSg1/BlwRgHRicGXR1vwEP/UTm63f8eb@Zc/o6cnZt6NtTnZ3amHKkrysG5bBwIGdKAmVQwRxSnsZegveDHjxC@uf395efP2JPYQnpy69vaRT8Su@KgYHFCqSVskAujXNKJ5pBPkwxF4hKI0fptIiVFAyKAbFCo7BSGG6MGSGR5AzsgOUKjVK5cDyXzlnUTifRB0dF5DqxDNTwMdYImxvFdWGLQSQxDOQYR2tto63ReZzqKaSLmsJaZ6I5d0qhFP8qkZO1LAyXhR5i/j/LoNYO0arpumnnLw)

#### How?

The recursive function \$g\$ first computes the unreduced numerator and denominator \$(N,D)\$ of \$H_{n,m}\$ and saves a copy of the final result into \$(p,q)\$:

```javascript
n ? g(n - 1, p = N * n**m + D, q = D * n**m) : ...
```

When \$n=0\$, it enters its 2<sup>nd</sup> phase where the GCD of \$(p,q)\$ is computed in \$N\$:

```javascript
... : D ? g(0, D, N % D) : ...
```

When \$D=0\$, it eventually returns:

```javascript
... : [p / N, q / N]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
1#.(%@^~1+i.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLakIxEIb3fYqhpVhpe5hLMhdBKBRcufIB3JRKdSPkAXz10zmaQ20gm3xf8v@Z0/g4LA6wXsEC3gBhlft9gM/ddjPS0/Dy/LG/0OtxWI7Lh@@vnzOwM1dqbBGisAaDAwjcGBUkEqVGHIq5kpfk2rmjEjqjNTO7CpNR06jdKEImUjBa4QgnjSnD0yhzBrXpiO5izQ29mDStXvX2qCT3zllVPUuZlivjZNZZZBa6h2W1FiLEiHMxu6vO1RrXuQzD3zCMVIPIpc/k//382PgL)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
*€:@S,:gɗɗP$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/rUdMaK4dgHav0k9NPTg9Q@X94uX7Wo4a5@pqR//9HG@somMfqKESb6SiYgGhTHQVTEG2io2ABooHyhiDaQkfBGESb6ygYQdWD9RlB1ZmC@AA)

A byte less than `*€µP:¹S,P:g/$`, but the abuse of `ɗ` leads me to believe this can be shorter yet.

```
*€              Raise each 1 .. n to the power of m.
         ɗP$    For that list and the product of its elements:
  :@            divide each by the product
    S           and sum;
        ɗ       for that sum:
     ,          pair it with the product,
      :         and divide both by
       g        the GCD of the sum and product.
```

Comment: I feel like there's some `ð` chaining able to be done here, but I can't figure anything out :/

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Outputting reversed pairs, [this is the same length](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/HKv3wBqtgLq1HTWsCDi9X@X94uX5o1qOGufqakf//RxvrKJjH6ihEm@komIBoUx0FUxBtoqNgAaKB8oYg2kJHwRhEm@soGEHVg/UZQdWZgvgA), so maybe you're on to something

Comment: I've not manged to find a save here but I do have `*€µṭP:\§µ:g/` and half a dozen variants (all outputting [denominator, numerator]) if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>155</s> 138 bytes

```java
int g(int a,int b){return b<1?a:g(b,a%b);}
m->n->{int p=1,d=0,t;for(;n>0;d=d*t+p,p*=t)t=(int)Math.pow(n--,m);return d/g(d,p)+"/"+p/g(d,p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU89b4MwEJ3jX2FFqmSDcRJ1qFQHulXqkClj1cFgoKZgW@ZIFSF@OzWtt95wd@/dx7vr5E1mnfpa9eCsB9wFzCfQPW8mU4G2hicCuansdYWrXo4jvkht8IxwsMiPICGEm9UKD6FKruC1ad8/pG9HOqPda9x1fjNQt7Vn/4i/iaJo8nXICpMVszaAXX5iKj8yEI31RJjiKFSuEkgdc0kOFHIS2uhFwid39puYLGMDFb6GyRusDi1RzNF0f9inLgKxrDuBdtf7CPXA7QTcBWXoDWm4dK6/kycak0dKxe@bS/wQbTe1mySWbPMlnaNWeT69yOeWlEw@lEEELesP)

$$Denominator_{n, m} = \prod_{k=1}^n k^m$$

$$Numerator_{n,m} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {Denominator_{n,m}} {k^m} = Numerator_{n-1,m} \times k^m + Denominator_{n-1,m}$$

## Java + Commons Lang 2, 127 bytes

```java
m->n->{org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction x=null;for(x=x.ZERO;n>0;)x=x.add(x.getFraction(1,(int)Math.pow(n--,m)));return x;}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>35</s> 24 bytes

```
[ [1,b] 0 rot - v^n Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNT8MwDL33V5g7W@J82AlIuyIuXBCnaUilBJjG2qoNk1C1X8P/4S@V0LUdOFKk2O89PzsveRGrpn@4v727uYK8bauihX0e34Zr2eTla2hhF5oyvJ9SH@W2qJ7D6XEIv/QW6ibE@Fk32zLCdZZ1GaTogEHDES5gsQLllLIoFHuvaSwboKmMRiJqQoHKk0wxQmw6I8RJQumUZMHMA2YCuaQ0goxG1tpIL4zy3iH5qRmevSCKKasTecyyY@kMa0HWWTqrqzTGNAQRueSRycxlPg/hU1/pnOfkVHitUUn536ealSwLZWnWsH/3xEjkEZ0e1zWpHPs1rPHyaQMSmirCAg6PJXx/wabvEn/4vdU@r6GNebFb9j8)

*-11 thanks to @Bubbler!*

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes two integers from the data stack as input and leaves a fully-reduced mixed fraction (it's simply the way that Factor is) on the data stack as output.

- `[1,b]` Make a range from `1` to `n`.
- `0 rot` Push `0` and bring `m` to the top of the stack.
- `-` Subtract `m` from `0`.
- `v^n` Raise every element in the range to the `-m` power.
- `Σ` Sum.

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVHBTsMwDL3vK8ydLXHS2glIuyIuXBCnaUilpDCNpSPJJk3Tvob/4ZdK2NoNHClS7Peen52mqlMbuqfH@4e7G6hibOsIqyq9H69JqPybi7B0wbsPaMLulG42vk6L1keI7nPjfO1OpMnGL@r21Z0eW/erHWEdXEq7dVj4BLej0X4EOfbAoOEAVzCegjJKlSgUW6upLxdAQxkLiagJBSpLMkcPKfPpIUYSSqMkC2Y@YgaQyUo9qNDIWhfSikJZa5Ds0AwvXhDFkNWZ3GfZsDQFa0GlKemirvIYwxBEZLJHpuJc5ssQNveVxljOToXVGpWU/32qs1LJQpV01ij/7omRyCIa3a9rUDl0M5jh9cscJIQ2wRi2zx6@v2De7TP/@LXTVbWGmKp6Oel@AA)

Comment: @Bubbler Wow, very nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
1#.#\@$^-@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZC5agMxEIb7PMUQB0wgXuaQ5jAYDAZXqVLbaUJMSGNQ5bdfS15tsgIV0nz8x/yOz8P6ArstrOENELb1bgY4fLwfR1oNq9P@5XOzP4@vT99fP1eQG1yAb9ODnTlTYYsQhd00tD6khESiVIhDsZ4KaANSBxyV0BmtmNmDaEhuSO5IEjKRhFESRzhpNJvUEJ9tqPxZU/8zN/RkUjR71knXGyBzcFX1msw0PYa2bBXVD93Dar4SIsSIuCwwN@RshXNz52WithUj1SBy6cv5V8iTwngH)

TFW J beats Jelly...

Used as `n f m`, where `n` and `m` are given as extended-precision integers.

#### How it works

```
1#.#\@$^-@]    NB. dyadic train; left = n, right = m
   #\@$        NB. 1..n in a dyadic context:
     @$        NB.   reshape m into dimension n, and then
   #\          NB.   get the lengths of prefixes
       ^       NB. each raised to the power of
        -@]    NB. -m
1#.            NB. sum of them
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
ɾ$eDΠ$/∑$Π":ġ/
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%24eD%CE%A0%24%2F%E2%88%91%24%CE%A0%22%3A%C4%A1%2F&inputs=8%0A3&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```
import math,rationals
func H(n,m:int):any=
 var r=0//1;for i in 1..n:r+=1//i^m
 r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvBCsIwDADQe78iR4thtWxT6ejdrxDCcCxg0xGrsK@vHqS3d3nCqVZOW9YCicqKSoWz0PNllrfMcDsIpsBSbCDZo4EPKWg8OeenJSswsIDvOgl6jN45vicDWh/zmn@3x4s1f59xaB5xbB7w2tyjt/UL)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 28 bytes

```
n#m=sum$map((1%).(^m))[1..n]
```

Comment: I think this requires an import to `Data.Ratio` to get `%`: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRLyixJDOfK08517a4NFclN7FAQ8NQVVNPIy5XUzPaUE8vL/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqCsbL5/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Though you can also force a rational output with normal arithmetic by specifying the type explicitly: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08517a4NDfaUL8iLremwkY32lBPLy821soqKLEkMz8vMed/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqCsbL5/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I admit it does. Does that cost any extra bytes, and if so, how many?

Comment: With the import, you just include it as part of the code [like this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRLyixJDOfK08517a4NFclN7FAQ8NQVVNPIy5XUzPaUE8vL/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqCsbL5/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA).

Comment: A few tips. 1) You can import `GHC.Real` instead of `Data.Ratio` for -2 bytes. 2) Using a list comprehension, you can shorten your code a bit: `n#m=sum[1%k^m|k<-[1..n]]`. 3) Instead of `import`ing `Data.Ratio` or ` GHC.Real`, you can actually use the `Prelude` function `toRational`: `n#m=sum[1/toRational k^m|k<-[1..n]]`, for a total of `35` bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ê☺σ;vù
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8801e53b7697&i=+7+,3%0A+4+,6%0A+5+,5%0A+8+,4%0A+1+,3%0A+3+,8%0A+2+,7%0A+7+,6%0A+8+,2%0A+7+,5%0A&m=2)

just another trivial answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
->n,m{(1..n).sum{|x|x**-m}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ7daw1BPL09Tr7g0t7qmoqZCS0s3t7b2f4FCWrSxjnnsfwA)

Comment: You can update your answer to ruby 2.7+ to make use of numbered arguments and save 2 bytes `->n,m{(1..n).sum{_1**-m}}`

Comment: It would not work on TIO, so I prefer to keep it this way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 91 bytes

```python
import math
f=lambda n,m,N=0,D=1:n and f(n-1,m,N*n**m+D,D*n**m)or(N/(G:=math.gcd(N,D)),D/G)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVHJTsMwEL3nK@YWu0ypl8RLpXCK1Ft/ADiUJKUVxIkSIwFVv73Ybosvb@Z55s02/vjD4KQZp8vl2I/D5KHf@UO2rz53/Vu7A4c9biuGdcXXDnauhT1xSx7ZhVss@oca62TQYSLbFdmsqyjw@N60ZIs1pVivNvTiu9nPUAEhEkFTBKIQioglQhmxQDARwz@PaBBkRI0gbvEpT9ziyujTrPseu8Z3bdIWRoiShwRtrVQxiheMc6kCx4VVLLykzRRnRrCgrbVOdOILybWUBbOhN2Gt4cpeVUJ@MrTRzBQ69KhKU6pbmlBKmVhCq@LK2KDBjLGaxdJWSi4Y@y8jyjhUmRRjy5orZTk38t75PZZmzaFrPropTpe/fAldNDlCsrjMabYfJvDYwdHB73EkacsI953QdQbhOYQegoJPXrxCOGHgaPLH6eg82ecnd0Y49WdYPsFpPsPpVvq5q6r59ZzTyx8)

Inputs \$n\$ and \$m\$ and returns the numerator and denominator of \$H_{n,m}\$ as a tuple.

Uses the formula from [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225865/9481).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <s>31</s> 27 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{(⊢÷∨/){⍵,⍨+/⍵÷x}∧/x←⍵*⍨⍳⍺}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9Z41LXo8PZHHSv0Nasf9W7VedS7QlsfyDi8vaL2Ucdy/YpHbROAXC2g@KPezY96d9UCAA&f=RY65FQIxDERzqlBoRzqtoyFKISOgAHLqoJStBO@uAUXz/ow02m6PK75f0BSiNwfrbcDozSD7ZNxbgvYWILs7I7IbY6rLdn@CpMhglKhSPwgbMaszspTTnIMmOVMKBUbEgU9uyqFqVGhSley1rjCeIjIoLRR95PDvmrh7zopwW6TmDcqsmEVYqixE/xoZgTL893KwezGnrs9X9gM&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

`(⊢÷∨/){⍵,⍨+/⍵÷x}∧/x←⍵*⍨⍳⍺` is equivelent to `x←(⍳⍺)*⍵⋄(⊢÷∨/){⍵,⍨+/⍵÷x}∧/x`.
APL translated to Python:

```python
from math import *

def H(n, m):
    x = [i**m for i in range(1,n+1)] # x←(⍳⍺)*⍵
    tmp = lcm(*x) # ∧/x
    tmp = (sum(tmp//i for i in x), tmp) # {⍵,⍨+/⍵÷x}
    tmp = [e//gcd(*tmp) for e in tmp] # (⊢÷∨/)
    return tmp
```

First I make a list from `1` to `n` -- `⍳⍺`.
Then I raise every element of the list to the power of `m` to calculate the value of all the denominators, and assign it to the variable `x` -- `x ← (⍳⍺)*⍵`.

I then calculate the denominator after all the fractions are added together by taking the least common multiple of all the elements of `x` (all the denominators) -- `∧/x`.

Next I create a two element tuple, the second element of which is the denominator -- `{⍵,⍨...}`. The first element is the numerator, calculated as the sum of the denominator divided by each of the original denominators -- `+/⍵÷x`.

Lastly, I simplify the fraction by dividing it by it's gcd -- `(⊢÷∨/)`.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl) page for ways you can golf your program, and check out the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard), a chat room for APL

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 70 bytes

```
=LET(k,SEQUENCE(A1)^B1,d,PRODUCT(k),n,SUM(d/k),g,GCD(n,d),n/g&"/"&d/g)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnCkQ0jwaai8YU5Ye?e=F4CVhU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
≔Ｘ…·¹ＮＮθ≔Πθη≔Σ÷ηθζ⊞υζ⊞υηＷζ«≔﹪ηιζ≔ιη»Ｉ÷υη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3LCsIwEEXX5iu6nIAuBBdCV6KbLpSiXxDT0Aykic2jhYrfHlNtUXE3M/eeM1wyyw1TMe6cw1pDaXphodBcBYedODNdC1gvs0Lfgj@F5ppSSv/3luZkVlhTBe6hTWf5OV9Ck7z@gB1WAuSIpMKQCmVwEsLvPIK9RCUyGGh2J4vJckxuZUYcJ3pO8A09SGlRe9gz57/@vZSU5jFuyDauOvUE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｘ…·¹ＮＮθ
```

Generate the first `n` powers of `m`.

```
≔Πθη≔Σ÷ηθζ
```

Calculate the product, then divide that by each power and take the sum.

```
⊞υζ⊞υη
```

Save the values for later.

```
Ｗζ«≔﹪ηιζ≔ιη»
```

Find the GCD.

```
Ｉ÷υη
```

Divide the saved values by the GCD.

Answer (score 1):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 111 bytes

```
fmod H is pr RAT . op __ : Nat Nat -> Rat . vars N M : Nat . eq 0 M = 0 . eq(s N)M = 1 / s N ^ M +(N M) . endfm
```

#### Example Session

```
             \||||||||||||||||||/
           --- Welcome to Maude ---
             /||||||||||||||||||\
         Maude 3.1 built: Oct 12 2020 20:12:31
         Copyright 1997-2020 SRI International
           Tue May 18 23:37:06 2021
Maude> fmod H is pr RAT . op __ : Nat Nat -> Rat . vars N M : Nat . eq 0 M = 0 . eq(s N)M = 1 / s N ^ M +(N M) . endfm
Maude> red 3 7 .
reduce in H : 3 7 .
rewrites: 17 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (17206 rewrites/second)
result PosRat: 282251/279936
Maude> red 6 4 .
reduce in H : 6 4 .
rewrites: 40 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result PosRat: 14011361/12960000
Maude> red 3 1 .
reduce in H : 3 1 .
rewrites: 17 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result PosRat: 11/6
Maude> red 2 8 .
reduce in H : 2 8 .
rewrites: 10 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result PosRat: 257/256
Maude> red 5 7 .
reduce in H : 5 7 .
rewrites: 32 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result PosRat: 2822716691183/2799360000000
```

#### Ungolfed

```
fmod GENERALIZED-HARMONIC-NUMBERS is
    protecting RAT .
    op H : Nat Nat -> Rat .
    vars N M : Nat .
    eq H(0, M) = 0 .
    eq H(s N, M) = 1 / (s N ^ M) + H(N, M) .
endfm
```

`H(N, M)` is the naive recursive definition of \$H_{n, m}\$. Maude's built-in rational number module automatically reduces fractions to lowest common denominator.

There's not *much* golfing we can do because only a handful of characters can separate identifiers (`(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `,`, and space). I've renamed the function operator `H` to `__` (juxtaposition of two values) in the golfed version to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/Octave, 25 bytes

```matlab
@(n,m)sum(1./sym(1:n).^m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPJ1ezuDRXw1BPv7gSSFnlaerF5Wr@T7NNzCu25krTMNYx1wRSZjomIMpUxxREmehYaILlDEGUhY4xiDLXMYKoBGswgigxBfL@AwA)
Anonymous function. Returns accurate value of symbolic type, which can represent real numbers (so rational numbers including).
Unfortunatelly, to my suprise, MATLAB doesn't implement that function, only non-generalized harmonic numbers (so only for [image: m=1]).